# Poisson regression with custom offset and link

Tags: r, logistic, poisson-regression, link-function, offset

I have the following model
$$Y \sim \operatorname{Poisson}\left(\frac{1}{1+\exp(\beta X)} E\right)$$
In other words, I have count data for Poisson process with exposure E and rate given by the logistic of the linearly estimated odds ratio.

How do I do this regression in R? Normally I'd use an offset for exposure or a custom link function for the logistic part, but I can't see how to combine both.

Comment: In case you've found an answer yourself, I'd appreciate if you'd share it with us.